# Merging two dataframes based on dates that are overlapped using python

Tags: python, date, join, merge

I have two dataframes, one that designates one characteristic and another that designates another characteristic, I wanted to join them, but in such a way that the result would be dependent of the intersection between dates.

df1:

|  | Key | in_date | out_date | char1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 01/01/2020 | 01/10/2020 | A |
| 1 | 1000 | 02/10/2020 | 10/12/2020 | B |
| 2 | 2000 | 01/01/2019 | 10/01/2019 | C |
| 3 | 2000 | 11/01/2019 | 01/10/2022 | D |
| 4 | 2000 | 02/10/2022 | 01/01/2023 | B |
| 5 | 2000 | 02/01/2023 | 31/12/2030 | L |

df2

|  | Key | st_date | end_date | char2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 01/05/2019 | 01/09/2020 | G |
| 1 | 1000 | 02/09/2020 | 10/11/2020 | GG |
| 2 | 2000 | 20/01/2019 | 15/02/2019 | K |
| 3 | 2000 | 16/02/2019 | 10/01/2022 | GE |
| 4 | 2000 | 11/01/2022 | 31/12/2030 | GG |

Desire result:

|  | key | start | end | char1 | char2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1000 | 01/05/2019 | 31/12/2019 | null | G |
| 1 | 1000 | 01/01/2020 | 31/08/2020 | A | G |
| 2 | 1000 | 01/09/2020 | 01/10/2020 | A | GG |
| 3 | 1000 | 02/10/2020 | 10/11/2020 | A | GG |
| 4 | 1000 | 11/11/2020 | 10/12/2020 | B | nan |
| 5 | 2000 | 01/01/2019 | 10/01/2019 | C | nan |
| 6 | 2000 | 11/01/2019 | 19/01/2019 | D | nan |
| 7 | 2000 | 20/01/2019 | 15/02/2019 | D | K |
| 8 | 2000 | 16/02/2019 | 10/01/2022 | D | GE |
| 9 | 2000 | 11/01/2022 | 01/10/2022 | D | GG |
| 10 | 2000 | 02/10/2022 | 01/01/2023 | B | GG |
| 11 | 2000 | 02/01/2023 | 31/12/2030 | L | GG |

I tried to use many if and else, but when I tried to aggregate the dataframe, didn't work.

I tried to use pd.merge but I have a sparse matrix

Comment: Please reformat your data so that we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited, it's better?

Comment: Please, check [Tables section of Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables).

Comment: @Dept , Yes thank you. I am currently trying to solve this in jupyter notebook if I can I will share the answer

Comment: You can use `print(df.to_markdown())` to have a string output that you can copy-paste for markdown tables.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar poblem in my line of work. The easiest way to tackle this problem is to synchronize both dataframes to ensure that all periods are the same. That means that if there is a break between two entries in one dataframe, you need to introduce it to the other as well.

This will lead to two dataframes that have the same values for `in_time` and `out_time`. Here is an example for a synchronizing function. The dataframes are transformed to dictionaries of the form:

```
df1 = {'Key': ['1000', '1000', '2000', '2000', '2000', '2000'], 'in_date': ['01/01/2020', '02/10/2020', '01/01/2019', '11/01/2019', '02/10/2022', '02/01/2023'], 'out_date': ['01/10/2020', '10/12/2020', '10/01/2019', '01/10/2022', '01/01/2023', '31/12/2030'], 'char1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'L']}

df2 = {'Key': ['1000', '1000', '2000', '2000', '2000'], 'in_date': ['01/05/2019', '02/09/2020', '20/01/2019', '16/02/2019', '11/01/2022'], 'out_date': ['01/09/2020', '10/11/2020', '15/02/2019', '10/01/2022', '31/12/2030'], 'char2': ['G', 'GG', 'K', 'GE', 'GG']}
```

The function is:

```
def synchronize(df1,df2):
    cuts1 = {}
    cuts2 = {}

    ## Define the cutpoints for each Key

    for i,key in enumerate(df1["Key"]):
        cuts = [datetime.strptime(df1["in_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y"),datetime.strptime(df1["out_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y")]
        try:
            cuts1[key]+=cuts
        except:
            cuts1[key]=cuts
        cuts1[key]=sorted(cuts1[key])

    for i,key in enumerate(df2["Key"]):
        cuts = [datetime.strptime(df2["in_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y"),datetime.strptime(df2["out_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y")]
        try:
            cuts2[key]+=cuts
        except:
            cuts2[key]=cuts
        cuts2[key]=sorted(cuts2[key])

    ## Now we have two lists of sorted cutpoints to split periods in the other data frame
    ## Extend both data frames to adhere to these cuts:

    outdf1 = {}
    outdf2 = {}
    for v in df1.keys(): outdf1[v] = []
    for v in df2.keys(): outdf2[v] = []

    for i,key in enumerate(df1["Key"]):
        st,et = datetime.strptime(df1["in_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y"),datetime.strptime(df1["out_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y")
        rcuts = []
        for c in cuts2[key]:
            if c>st and c<et: ## Cut within this session
                rcuts.append(c)

        if len(rcuts)==0:
            periods = [(st,et)]
        else:
            periods = [(st,rcuts[0])]
            for ci in range(len(rcuts)-1):
                periods.append((rcuts[ci],rcuts[ci+1]))
            periods.append((rcuts[-1],et))

        for p in periods:
            outdf1["Key"].append(key)
            outdf1["in_date"].append(p[0].strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
            outdf1["out_date"].append(p[1].strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
            outdf1["char1"].append(df1["char1"][i])

    for i,key in enumerate(df2["Key"]):
        st,et = datetime.strptime(df2["in_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y"),datetime.strptime(df2["out_date"][i],"%d/%m/%Y")
        rcuts = []
        for c in cuts1[key]:
            if c>st and c<et: ## Cut within this session
                rcuts.append(c)

        if len(rcuts)==0:
            periods = [(st,et)]
        else:
            periods = [(st,rcuts[0])]
            ci=0
            for ci in range(len(rcuts)-1):
                periods.append((rcuts[ci],rcuts[ci+1]))
            periods.append((rcuts[-1],et))

        for p in periods:
            outdf2["Key"].append(key)
            outdf2["in_date"].append(p[0].strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
            outdf2["out_date"].append(p[1].strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
            outdf2["char2"].append(df2["char2"][i])

    return outdf1,outdf2
```

Calling this function as: `new_df1,new_df2 = synchronize(df1,df2)` will result in two new dataframes with the following contents:

```
#new_df1
Key     in_date     out_date    char1
1000    01/01/2020  01/09/2020  A
1000    01/09/2020  02/09/2020  A
1000    02/09/2020  01/10/2020  A
1000    02/10/2020  10/11/2020  B
1000    10/11/2020  10/12/2020  B
2000    01/01/2019  10/01/2019  C
2000    11/01/2019  20/01/2019  D
2000    20/01/2019  15/02/2019  D
2000    15/02/2019  16/02/2019  D
2000    16/02/2019  10/01/2022  D
2000    10/01/2022  11/01/2022  D
2000    11/01/2022  01/10/2022  D
2000    02/10/2022  01/01/2023  B
2000    02/01/2023  31/12/2030  L

## new_df2
Key     in_date     out_date    char2
1000    01/05/2019  01/01/2020  G
1000    01/01/2020  01/09/2020  G
1000    02/09/2020  01/10/2020  GG
1000    01/10/2020  02/10/2020  GG
1000    02/10/2020  10/11/2020  GG
2000    20/01/2019  15/02/2019  K
2000    16/02/2019  10/01/2022  GE
2000    11/01/2022  01/10/2022  GG
2000    01/10/2022  02/10/2022  GG
2000    02/10/2022  01/01/2023  GG
2000    01/01/2023  02/01/2023  GG
2000    02/01/2023  31/12/2030  GG
```

Now, you can merge the two dataframes using the `Key`, `in_date` and `out_date` as keys.

Note that there are 1-day periods where nothing was defined. For example, the period for Key 1000 and char A in dataframe1 is interrupted by the end of a period on 1.9.2020 and a beginning of another one on 2.9.2020.

After merging, you may need to clean up the dates, subtracting one day from `out_time` timestamps where they are the same as the next `in_time` timestamp and removing the now existing 0-day periods. But you can only do this **after** merging, as the dates would not match up, otherwise.